# Validation - front end and feed file - is it efficient using same framework?

Tags: validation, struts, drools

I have a java based web application that is around 7 years old and have grown organically over time. It has been - historically - a mvc based application. Users used to put in data which used to be validated using the standard mvc based validations i.e. Struts. Somewhere down the line, we had to use Drools to do some validations for feed files that were coming in from other sources. The Drools based validation have worked quite well.

However, now we have a problem. There are a few validations that are in the MVC i.e. Struts. There are a few validations that are in Drools. While they both work perfectly fine in their own areas, we have duplication of validations. Also, as expected we have had issues around validations present in one scenario and not in the other. Of course, the tactical fix is that we keep a good grasp over all validations and ensure that any data coming in - whether through front end or from feed files - go through all validations. It should work but this is labour intensive and error prone.

I am polling the group to find if there is some strategic solution to this. Is there anyway I can move the validations in a single repository and have both front end data and feed data go through the same validations? The easiest answer seems to be that I move all validations to Drools and ensure that the front end interacts with Drools to execute all validations. Of course Drools is handling - and will continue to handle - all feed based data. I am also aware that Drools - perhaps - was not intended to be used this way and hence would not have been my first choice for any validation for data from web based front end.

Is there some other way? Have you faced this problem? If so have you managed to solve this problem? If so, how?

Thanks for reading. And a thanks a ton for any response.